# how to reference a non static object in a static method

Tags: c#, methods, static, textbox

I've created a textbox and want to reference it in a static methd. how can I do that?
here;s my code

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textbox2 = new TextBox();
        textbox2.Text = "A";
    }

    static void gettext() 
    {
        textbox2.Text = "B"; //here is my problem
    }
```

Comment: You can't. You need an object.

Comment: Also notice that in your code textbox2 in Form1_Load is local to the method, not to the class. Define Textbox textbox2 outside Form1_Load

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property-wi

Comment: please tell me how. Im new to c#.

Comment: can anybody tell me how can I make an object reference to texbox2 in my static method?

Comment: Your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15316651/1174942) is about the same thing and is answered perfectly. Please read it carefully. You need to study about `static` and instances.

Answer (score 6):

You would need to pass it into the static method somehow, easiest option is to just expand the method signature to accept the textbox:

```
static void gettext(TextBox textBox) 
{
    textBox.Text = "B"; //here is my problem
}
```

Comment: @user1853846 Don't forget to accept the answer you feel is the best (in this case, Lloyd's)

Answer (score 4):

You should give your textbox as a parameter to the static method

```
static void gettext(TextBox textbox)
{
    textbox.Text = "B";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you understand what static means, static means that it belongs to the CLASS not an INSTANCE of the class. Possibly a better solution to your problem would be to create an instance method which set the text.

```
// private variable
private TextBox textbox2;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // refers to private instance variable
    textbox2 = new TextBox();
    textbox2.Text = "A";
}

private void gettext() 
{
    // refers to private instance variable
    textbox2.Text = "B";
}
```

If you're having difficulty understanding `static`, odds are you don't need to use it. Static members are available to all instances of a class but don't belong to any of them, which means static methods cannot access private members.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? It doesn't make use of `static` methods, but as far as I can see, this is a totally valid answer, am I missing something?

Comment: also not sure why (it is not directly answering the explicit question, yes, but it certainly gives what is likely the best and most useful answer, in my mind) +1

Answer (score 2):

You can do so

```
static void gettext(TextBox textbox2) 
{
    textbox2.Text = "B";
}
```

And in code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    YourClass.gettext(textbox2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a static variable set on Load :

```
private static readonly TextBox _textBox = new TextBox();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _textBox.Text = "A";
}

static void gettext()  
{ 
    _textbox2.Text = "B";
}
```

Comment: The textBox is readonly and never reassigned, only the Text property. If you prefer, you remove the readonly and create the TextBox on the Load method.