# How to reference a non-static object from a static WebMethod? - aspx, ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I'm using a combination of aspx webforms and AJAX calls. I want to store variables privately on the C# end that are passed back and forth using ajax (then eventually save those variables to a SQL database before logout).

*I've seen [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336369/how-to-reference-a-non-static-object-in-a-static-method) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property-wi) though I'm still unsure*

Here's what some of my javascript file looks like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Index.aspx/DoStuff",
  data: JSON.stringify({ 'someVariable': varStr }),
  ...
});
```

My main structure of `Index.aspx.cs` is like so:

```
static SomeCollection g_Collection;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  g_Collection = new SomeCollection();
}

[WebMethod]
public static string DoStuff(string someVariable)
{
  g_Collection.Add(someVariable);
}

// At some point ajax also calls another method that saves
// the g_Collection to a database *for that user* (important)
// - based on their GUID
```

For a single user everything works fine, however, when multiple users login the `g_Collection` gets saved as a singly used variable (as expected since the `g_Collection` variable is `static`).
i.e. if 2 logged in users called the `DoStuff()` they would be adding to the same `g_Collection` instance.

Since the method `DoStuff()` is `static` I've declared `g_Collection` as `static` as well. 
How do I create instances of `g_Collection` instead?
What do I need to declare (inside the `Page_Load()`?) so that g_Collection is an instance to a logged in user, while still keeping the same functionality in my `static` `[WebMethod]` methods?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to use a static member in this scenario.

- If you want a collection per user, you should probably simply use a [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx) object.
- If you want a global collection (1 for all users), an [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.application%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object.

Comment: Session Approach Fails when we open Application in Different Tab.Both Tab may send different Data.